how to get a series of all time high?
I am trying to write a Pine Script function that will take a series of data (e.g., [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ..., 100]) and return a new series where every element is replaced by the highest value in the input series (in this case, [100, 100, ..., 100]).
Here is what I have so far:
highest(data=close) =>
    // need the highest number for each array element of ALL, NOT just before that value

Currently, highest() only considers the highest value up to the current point in the series. However, I need the function to evaluate the highest value across the entire series and use that value for every element.
What I’ve tried:

Using ta.highest(), but it only works for the highest value up to the current element, not for the entire series. (need to look forward and backward)

Goal:
To transform an input series like [1, 2, 3, 100(maximum),...34] into [100, 100, ..., 100].
My final goal is to transfer the price into 0,1 scale. Thats why im using min-max normalization.
How can I achieve this?

You cannot do that and it does not make sense if you think a little bit.
Your script is executed on each bar. You need to understand that. Even you have all the bars available on your chart, once the execution starts, it will start from the very first bar on your chart. And at that point, you don't have access to any further bars (even though they have already been formed in reality).
You can never know the absolute min or max of your range. New bars will form and they might have a new max or min. You cannot go back and change your plot once you have new information. What's plotted will stay there. You might try using lines but that also does not make too much sense.
You need to make your min and max dynamic and live with the consequences.
You can try something like below:
normalize(_src, _min, _max) =>
    // Normalizes series with unknown min/max using historical min/max.
    // _src      : series to rescale.
    // _min, _min: min/max values of rescaled series.
    var _historicMin =  10e10
    var _historicMax = -10e10
    _historicMin := math.min(nz(_src, _historicMin), _historicMin)
    _historicMax := math.max(nz(_src, _historicMax), _historicMax)
    _min + (_max - _min) * (_src - _historicMin) / math.max(_historicMax - _historicMin, 10e-10)

norm_close = normalize(close, 0, 1)

plot(norm_close)

For more details, see this.

Thanks, but that normalize will give you the min or max look backward, not forwards.  If my script execute on each bar, maybe if it's last bar do something to get all time high?

That's what I'm saying. You figure out the all time high on the last bar and then what? You cannot go back and plot something on the previous bars.

That's weird design, hard to plot multiple chart with different scales in one panel...

Did you try the function I shared? It does a good job for most cases.

Yes, that is the first function I tried, but that makes all the new high in 1(max), future max also 1, that is not real normalization. Check the link
